# Does anyone know this logo?

Tags: bmx, badge

This is a old school BMX, I think, but can't figure what brand this logo is?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VneUGs9oFMM_WWO0pQxipb20Wg3axEoX/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Please use [edit] to "inline" your images.   Your google drive link shows "request access" and that's not something I want to share.

Comment: Yes, please add the image(s) to your question, not a link to them.